# Как создать и передать переменную с user_id из одного handler'а в другой? (Python, Aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

**Дана функция отзывов:**

*•По команде /fb пользователю отправляется сообщение*

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('fb'))
async def fb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Напишите, что хотите отправить автору')
    await fb_states.waiting_for_fb.set()
```

*•После отправки отзыва присылается сообщение пользователю и админу*

```
@dp.message_handler(state=fb_states.waiting_for_fb)
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,
                                  inline_keyboard=[
                                      [
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ответить', callback_data='answer'),
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Прочитано', callback_data='read')
                                      ]
                                  ])
    user = message.from_user.username
    answer = message.text
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Отзыв отправлен!')
    for admin in admins:
        try:
            await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=admin, text=f'Поступил отзыв от @{user}:\n'
                                                          f'"{answer}"', reply_markup=markup)
        except Exception as err:
            logging.exception(err)
```

*•По нажатию у админа на кнопку "Ответить" присылается сообщение*

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='answer', state=fb_states.waiting_for_answer)
async def state2(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup()
    await call.message.answer('Напишите ответ на отзыв')
    await fb_states.waiting_for_answer.set()
```

*•После отправления админу приходит сообщение, но пользователю не приходит*

```
@dp.message_handler(state=fb_states.waiting_for_answer)
async def state3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Ответ отправлен!')
    try:
        await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=f'Поступил ответ на отзыв:\n'
                                                        f'"{answer}"')
    except Exception as err:
        logging.exception(err)
```

---

```
class fb_states(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_fb = State()
    waiting_for_answer = State()
```

---

Нужно каким-то образом, чтобы во 2-ом handler'е создавалась переменная с user_id, которая потом бы использовалась в последнем handler'е для отправки сообщение пользователю. Помогите пожалуйста это реализовать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UРД: Ах да, чуть не забыл, вам не обязательно использовать целиком мой код, основная идея была в том, как передать и получить `ID user'a.`

---

Мой вариант будет отличаться, я написал его не исходя из вашего кода. В моем случае отсутствует FSM автоматы.

Первое, что я сделал это кнопки:

```
#Кнопка отправить, и отменить(удалить) отправку
def sendBtn():
    send = InlineKeyboardButton("Send", callback_data="send")
    cancel = InlineKeyboardButton("Cancel", callback_data="cancel")
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard.add(send, cancel)
    return keyboard
```

Следующим шагом давайте распишем логику этих кнопок:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text = "send")
async def sendToadm(call:types.CallbackQuery):
    id_user = call.from_user.id #Самое интересное - мы передадим в сообщении админу id юзера, которое мы без труда потом достанем.
    username = call.from_user.username #у вас был юзер нейм, пусть для красоты тут тоже будет.
    await call.bot.send_message(id_admin, f'ID: "{id_user}"\nUsername: "{username}"\n{call.message.text}')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text = "cancel")
async def delmsg(call:types.CallbackQuery):
    #Тут просто удаляю сообщение, если пользователь не захотел отправлять, или ошибся в написанном.
    await call.bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
```

Самое вкусное:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def sendTouser(message:types.Message):
    if(message.reply_to_message): #Когда админ увидит сообщение от пользоваетля, ему будет достаточно просто ответить(reply) на него. и сразу отправить через бота юзеру
        user_id = message.reply_to_message.text.split('"')[1] #Я говорил выше, самое интересное это id usera, которое мы получили вместе с сообщением
        await bot.send_message(user_id, f'from admin:\n{message.text}')#Отправка вашего сообщения от бота - пользователю
    else:
        await message.reply(message.text, reply_markup=sendBtn()) #Этот фрагмент я отображу на скриншоте
```

---

Принцип работы:

1. После того, как я отправил сообщение я сразу получил возможность отправить или отменить message:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Когда пользователь отправил админу сообщение, оно приходит ему в такой форме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Из вышеуказанного мне достаточно просто сделать reply_to_message и произойдет магия(из-за split):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Финал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я сразу хочу обратить ваше `!ВНИМАНИЕ!` т.к. я общался и за админа и за юзера, все происходило в одном `чате!`, соответственно при `транспонировании` моего кода под ваш вы должны все тщательно проверить, сходиться ли все по `id`.

---

Как по мне, идеальный вариант(с учетом допиливания всех фич) для отзывов, или сообщений админам и тд. Просто и без пафоса. И не нужен лишний автомат.

Comment: спасибо большое! очень помог